# How to run a conditional aggregation against a varchar column that contains numbers and text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm fairly new to SQL Server 2008 and I've run into a problem. I have a table which contains a varchar(255) column with lab results. The data in the column looks something like this:

```
result_value
7.0
162
NEGATIVE
SEE NOTE
9.6
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is run the following query:

```
;WITH PatientData (patient_id,last_name, first_name, ethnic_group,
race, icdcode, encounter_date, test_performed, result_value,
result_units )
AS
(
SELECT pat.patient_id, pat.last_name, Pat.first_name, pat.ethnic_group,
pat.race, pl.icdcode, enc.encounter_date, lab.test_performed, lab.result_value,
lab.result_units
FROM dbo.dem_patient pat
RIGHT JOIN dbo.med_problemlist as pl
ON pat.patient_id = pl.patient_id
JOIN dbo.enc_encounter as enc
ON pat.patient_id = enc.patient_id
JOIN dbo.med_labresult as lab
ON pat.patient_id = lab.patient_id
WHERE pl.icdcode like '250%' AND
enc.encounter_date >= '01/01/2012' AND enc.encounter_date <= '12/31/2012' AND
pat.last_name != 'test' AND (lab.test_performed = 'HgbA1c' OR 
lab.test_performed = 'Hemoglobin A1c')
GROUP BY pat.patient_id, pat.last_name, Pat.first_name, pat.ethnic_group,
pat.race, pl.icdcode, enc.encounter_date, lab.test_performed, lab.result_value,
lab.result_units
)
select sum(case when result_value < 7.0 then 1 else 0 end) as [LessThan7%],
       sum(case when result_value >= 7.0 and result_value < 8.0 then 1 else 0 end) as [7%to8%],
       sum(case when result_value >= 8.0 and result_value < 9.0 then 1 else 0 end) as [8%to9%],
       sum(case when result_value >= 9.0 then 1 else 0 end) as [GreaterThan9%]
FROM PatientData pd1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT patient_id 
                FROM PatientData pd2 
                WHERE pd2.patient_id  = pd1.patient_id  
                GROUP BY patient_id 
                HAVING COUNT(*)>1 )
```

Since I should only be returning the patients who have had an A1c test performed, the results_value column should always look like x.x - however, which I try to run this query, I get "Arithmic overflow error converting varchar to datatype numeric.

Although I realize that putting these different types of data together in the same column is not ideal, I didn't create the database - I just have to use it. Is there anyway around this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you considered using **ISALPHA** to weed out "non-numeric" values?

Comment: I've done some research, but could you give me an example of how this could help?

Comment: My assumption was that your problem was due to implicit casting of text to numbers. So if you can determine that your field is not effectively numeric, then you can hopefully exclude it from your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of solution. Lets consider this table and data.

```
CREATE TABLE [tb](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
[result] [varchar](50) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] 
INSERT [tb] ([id], [result]) VALUES (1, N'12')
INSERT [tb] ([id], [result]) VALUES (2, N'24')
INSERT [tb] ([id], [result]) VALUES (3, N'35')
INSERT [tb] ([id], [result]) VALUES (4, N'NEGATIVE')
INSERT [tb] ([id], [result]) VALUES (5, N'SEE NOTE')
INSERT [tb] ([id], [result]) VALUES (6, N'15.5')
INSERT [tb] ([id], [result]) VALUES (7, N'16.4')
```

You can use ASCII function (ASCII Returns the ASCII code value of the leftmost character of a character expression.) to get correct numbers from this sample data

```
 select id,ascii(result),convert(decimal(16,2),result) as result from tb
 where ascii(result)>=ascii('0') and ascii(result)<=ascii('9')
  union 
 select id,ascii(result),-1.0 as result from tb
 where ascii(result)<=ascii('0') or ascii(result)>=ascii('9')
```

You can mark invalid records as you want. You can add more logic to this query. You can use this as subquery or with "join".
 I hope that it will help you.

Marcin Pazgier